# How to predict a set of outputs from a set of inputs using machine learning?

Tags: multiclass-classification

I have a set of data points that evolve over time as my input. Let us denote this by `X(t) = \[x1 x2 x3.....xn\](t)` at any time t. The corresponding output be `Y(t) = \[y1 y2 y3....ym\](t)`. I want to feed X and Y to the machine learning model and learn the relationship between them, so that when I give the next set of `X(t+1)`, the model predicts `Y(t+1)`.

Is this a problem of multi-label classification?

Comment: kindly elaborate your problem so that stack overflow community will be able to help you more specifically. Kindly give the code you tried and the problem you are having with the code. (like errors)

Answer (score 0):

You can predict values from any of the machine learning classifier by just calling 
predict function.Like the code below.

```
from sklearn import tree
dtr = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
dtr.fit(X_train,y_train)
y_head_dtr = dtr.predict(X_test)
```

At first you are fitting your model and than with the help of predict function you will get prediction.